PostgreSQL - Replacing pg_dump -o parameter when migrating to newer PostgreSQL version?
The pg_dump -o parameter was removed in PostgreSQL 12. What should I replace it with when migrating from PostgreSQL 9 to 14?
-o
--oids
Dump object identifiers (OIDs) as part of the data for every table. Use this option if your application references the OID columns in some way (e.g., in a foreign key constraint). Otherwise, this option should not be used.

PostgreSQL 11 pg_dump documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-pgdump.html (-o parameter exist)
PostgreSQL 12pg_dump documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html (-o parameter is removed)
I can only find this about OIDS in the 12.x release notes:
Simplify renumbering manually-assigned OIDs, and establish a new project policy for management of such OIDs (John Naylor, Tom Lane)

Patches that manually assign OIDs for new built-in objects (such as new functions) should now randomly choose OIDs in the range 8000—9999. At the end of a development cycle, the OIDs used by committed patches will be renumbered down to lower numbers, currently somewhere in the 4xxx range, using the new renumber_oids.pl script. This approach should greatly reduce the odds of OID collisions between different in-process patches.

While there is no specific policy reserving any OIDs for external use, it is recommended that forks and other projects needing private manually-assigned OIDs use numbers in the high 7xxx range. This will avoid conflicts with recently-merged patches, and it should be a long time before the core project reaches that range.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/
Thanks!
